# How to make shortcut for each characters in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

There is a RichTextBox which if user enter any key it will show in there. I tried GetAsyncKeyState for "." and "-" and etc but it doesn't work however A-Z and 0-9 work correctly.

```
Private Sub tmrKeys_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrKeys.Tick
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim key As String = Nothing
    Dim p As Boolean = CBool(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.P))
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dec As Boolean = CBool(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Decimal))
    Dim subtract As Boolean = CBool(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Subtract))
    Dim add As Boolean = CBool(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Add))



    Try
        For i = 2 To 90
            result = 0
            result = GetAsyncKeyState(i)
            If result = -32767 Then
                key = Chr(i)
                If i = 13 Then key = vbNewLine

                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        If key <> Nothing Then
            If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown OrElse My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock Then
                txtlogs.Text &= key.ToUpper
            ElseIf key = vbBack Then
                If txtlogs.TextLength > 0 Then
                    txtlogs.Text = txtlogs.Text.Remove(txtlogs.TextLength - 1)
                End If
            ElseIf My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
                txtlogs.Text &= " -[CTRL+" & key & "]"
            ElseIf subtract = True Then
                txtlogs.Text &= "-"
            ElseIf My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown AndAlso subtract = True Then
                txtlogs.Text &= "_"
            ElseIf dec = True Then
                txtlogs.Text &= "."
            Else
                txtlogs.Text &= key.ToLower
            End If
        End If
```

I want when user press decimal in the keyboard RichTextBox shows add "." to the text and so on

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Perhaps you could take a step back and explain why you seem to be attempting to re-interpret keyboard activity rather than letting windows handle input normally?

Comment: Because I want when even program is minimized it also get the characters and put in that RichTextBox

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a low-level keyboard hook then. Stephen Toub's written [an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) in C#, should be translatable to VB.Net with a little effort. That way Windows *notifies* you when keys are pressed, you don't have to implement e.g. key repeat, etc.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever proposes something on the lines of what I intended to write and additionally now I am doing something else. Convert this code to VB.NET and you will get a much more reliable approach to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the correct keycodes for the hyphen and the period, add these to your for loop:

```
If i = 189 Then key = "-"
If i = 190 Then key = "."
```

Also, to get the underscore and smaller-than sign, add these after your for loop:

```
If key = "-" AndAlso My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then key = "_"
If key = "." AndAlso My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then key = ">"
```